# Echo an $_POST in PHP

Tags: php, http-post

How can I print a `$_POST`?

Example:

```
echo $_POST['data'];
```

This returns nothing...

Comment: What's wrong with echo $_POST['data']?

Comment: Did you actually put something in 'data'?

Comment: It doesent return anything, yes, I've put something in data

Comment: If data's there, it should show up when you do var_dump or print_r, like I described below.  Could you show us the output of that?  Or describe how you're getting data into POST (web form, HTTP tool like Firebug or Fiddler, etc.)?

Comment: Try with _GET['data'] instead and pass a ?data=HelloWorld in your URL. Does that work?

Comment: Get works but problem solved, thanks everyone for your time/help :)

Comment: I would also recommend that you develop with `E_ALL` error reporting so you get a notice when a variable is not defined.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can also wrap your code with `<pre>` tags to make your array prints out nicer instead of just 1 continuous line.  A trick that was shown by a member on this site.

```
<pre>
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code is correct.

You can use either:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

or

```
print_r($_POST);
```

to print out the entire POST array for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can only show the values of keys that exist. [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) returns an array containing the keys that exist in the array. If there is no output for a key despite the fact that the key exists then the array may contain an empty value for that key.

Comment: ... Could I write an example of how to call a function? Is that what you're asking?